# Is Shacharit before dawn okay?

Tags: women, shemoneh-esrei, zemanim

If a person is tight on time, is it okay to pray the amidah before dawn if you're a girl?

Comment: Before dawn is still the time for Maariv. (I don't know what gender has to do with anything)

Comment: see http://www.aish.com/atr/Earliest-Time-for-Morning-Prayers-Shacharit.html

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps the OP is suggesting that since women are exempt from *mitzvot aseh shehazman grama*, they are not bound by the same *zmanim* as men.

Comment: @Loewian That suggestion doesn't seem relevant to the question of the time for Shacharit.

Comment: @d How do you figure?